# datediff (minute, '23:30','24:00') error

Tags: sql

In SQL 2008 why do I get an error when I do this:

```
select datediff (minute, '23:30','24:00')
```

The error is :

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Even if I were to change `24:00` to `00:00` why does the result say `-1410`?

What are the alternatives that I could use for this please?

Comment: It seems to me that 24:00 isn't valid time in SQL.  As I know, 24 hour format goes from 00:00 to 23:59

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for the difference between '23:30' and '24:00' - which technically is the next day, then you will use

```
select datediff (minute, '2012-07-10 23:30','2012-07-11 00:00')
```

When you use:

```
select datediff (minute, '23:30','00:00')
```

the '00:00' is being interpreted as the same day that is why you are getting `-1410`. There are a total of 1440 minutes in the day minus 30 minutes as the difference. The `DATEDIFF` function is:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

If your end date '00:00' is before your start date then you will get a negative number.

Edit:

Based on your comment you will use the following for your table, then use a `CASE` statement around the `endtime` to add a day to it:

```
select datediff(minute
                , starttime
                , case 
                when endtime = '00:00' 
                then dateadd(d, 1, endtime)
                else endtime END)
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e6ee/1)

Comment: Thank you, I have two columns, start_time and end_time... so what is the best way to get the number of minutes between the two please? do I simply need to do a datediff(days,-1,end_time) when end_time = 00:00? is there a better way? the column has no date component. only time

Answer (score 0):

The result says -1410 because there are 1,410 minutes between 23:00 the preceding 00:00.